# GtkNotebook does not show tab label content

Tags: gtk3

In an application with a GtkNotebook and a GtkBox as tab label, the tab label is visible, but the content of the tab label is not. How can  I make the content of the tab label visible?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget* notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
    GtkWidget* page_content = gtk_label_new("Content");
    GtkWidget* tab_label = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    GtkWidget* label_content_1 = gtk_label_new("Title");
    GtkWidget* label_content_2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Close");

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(tab_label), label_content_1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(tab_label), label_content_2, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), page_content, tab_label);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);

    gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));

    gtk_main();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code looks OK. Did you try `gtk_widget_show` on `tab_label`, `page_content`, `tab_label`? This shouldn't be necessary as you call `gtk_widget_show_all`, but I can't see anything else that might be wrong.

Comment: BTW. You could use [Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector) to see whether widgets are there.

Comment: @el.pescado `gtk_widget_show_all(tab_label)` solved the problem.

Comment: That sounds like bug in `GtkNotebook` or `gtk_show_all`, as `gtk_widget_show_all(window);` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by showing the widgets in `GTK_BOX` explicitly, and calling `gtk_notebook_set_show_tabs`:

```
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget* notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
    GtkWidget* page_content = gtk_label_new("Content");
    GtkWidget* tab_label = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    GtkWidget* label_content_1 = gtk_label_new("Title");
    GtkWidget* label_content_2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Close");

    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(label_content_1));
    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(label_content_2));
    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(tab_label));
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(tab_label), label_content_1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(tab_label), label_content_2, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), page_content, tab_label);
    gtk_notebook_set_show_tabs(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), TRUE);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);

    gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));

    gtk_main();
}
```

I am not in a position to explain the reason behind that though.
You may find this [link](https://gist.github.com/alpinechough/797575) about tabs with close button interesting.